# Requests in a for loop using TediousJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tedious

I'm writing a script in NodeJS to iterate over an excel file, perform some operations over it, and then insert multiple rows in MSSQL (multiple inserts per excel row). This means I have to iterate over the file and send the SQL statements to be executed against my Tedious connection.

I'm constantly running through this error:

> Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentLogin7WithStandardLogin state

```js
    wb.xlsx.readFile(filePath).then(function() {
        var sh = wb.getWorksheet('Sheet Name');

        // We start from row 11, the previous ones are not relevant
        for (i = 11; i <= sh.rowCount; i++) {
            // Iterate over each cell
            for (j = 1; j <= sh.getRow(i).cellCount; j++) {
                if (sh.getRow(10).getCell(j).value == 'X') {
                    // Build the query
                    let query = `INSERT INTO ...`;
                    
                    // Create the request
                    const request = new Request(query, function (err) {
                            if (err)
                                throw err;
                        }
                    );

                    // Execute the statement
                    connection.execSql(request);
                }
            }
        }
```

According to the [Tedious' FAQs](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/frequently-encountered-problems.html):

> Only one query can be executed on a connection at a time. You need to wait until the request callback is executed, either with an error or with the result before making another request.

The first iteration of the loops works normally. It inserts the row into the database, but as the next one tries to execute, I receive the previous error.

What's the best way to achieve this? I've tried to catch the **requestCompleted** event and using *connection.reset()* in the callback, but apparently that didn't work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If there's such limitation imposed, you have two options:

- Send your statements sequentially (in series) - wait for the previous one to complete before sending another one. You can achieve this with the `async` package's [series()](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#series) function or you can implement your own async queue.
- Combine all values into one single SQL `insert` statement (batch) and send it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The second one wouldn't be possible since it's expected to insert +1000 rows. I already tried it and the query was denied for reaching the 1000 insert limit. I'm currently taking a glance at the first option. I will report back.